# CSS media type: How to load CSS for mobile?

Tags: css, mobile, opera-mini, media-type

With this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="media/css/mobile.css"
      media="handheld" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="media/css/screen.css"
      media="screen" />
```

on my *N78* the nokia's default browser and opera mini load *screen.css* instead of *mobile.css*.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Nokia N78 uses the S60 browser, which reads only "screen" stylesheets. It won't read the "handheld". It doesn't support media query. Instead of trying to type everything here, have a look at this article and you will solve the problem - http://www.alistapart.com/articles/return-of-the-mobile-stylesheet

Answer (score 9):

Using the iPhone as an example:

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
href="iPhone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I have no idea which browsers/devices this does and does not work for.  The only mobile device I've developed for is the iPhone.  But I'm sure you can give it a shot with your nokia.

[More on media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 1):

Opera Mini uses the media type screen because it fits its behavior and capabilities best. However, it will use handheld stylesheets if you switch to mobile view mode. See [A developer’s look at Opera Mini 5 beta 2](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-5-beta-developers/) for more information.