# Responsive web design css file load for pc

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have an HTML5 responsive web site and i have a link on the view for mobile devices which will go to pc view when user clik on it. But my problem is how can i load the css codes for pc view when the user click to this link ?

Comment: Is it another HTML page? or is it the same document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen resolution will probably be the deciding factor for you. Here are 2 ideas:

First Idea (in the HEAD of the HTML):

```
<link media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)"
href="iPhone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Second Idea: Use Javascript to switch out the stylesheets.

I got some information from another post: [CSS media type: How to load CSS for mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248756/css-media-type-how-to-load-css-for-mobile)

Comment: Okay, i got the idea but do i have to add this css link to all html pages related to this web site ?

Comment: Yes, I would think so. Because each page needs to know what stylesheet to use. Without it it would not know what file to fetch and inject into the web render.